# Problem about listing network instances on SSMS

Tags: ssms, network

I have a problem about listing network instances on SSMS. When I look at the Network Instances on SSMS, it shows only local server instances. By the way, it shows all the instances on the network until today.

The only change I did is using commands below, but I don't think this issue related to this commands;

- ipconfig /flushdns
- ipconfig /registerdns
- ipconfig /release
- ipconfig /renew
- netsh int ip reset
- netsh winsock reset

I tried these;

- I'm sure that all instances I expect to see is under the same subnet.
- All instances' TCP/IP's are enabled and not hidden.
- All instance' allows remote connections.
- SQLServer's are running.
- SQLBrowser's are running.
- TCP port 1433 and UDP port 1434 are not blocked by firewall.
- I can ping these servers properly.
- I can connect these servers by using instance name. (Like PC3/SQLEXPRESS)

Thanks for advance.
OE